# Usage of the verb "provide"

Tags: verbs, prepositions, transitivity

Does the verb "provide" always have to be used with "with"? For example,

> Can you provide me *with* some good
> examples?
>
> Can you provide me some good
> examples?
>
> Can you provide some good
> examples?

I suppose it's a transitive verb, isn't it?

Moreover, is the following type of usage correct?

> You should provide food for your dog
> before you go on vacation.

If you could give me some good examples regarding "provide" with different types of usage, I'd appreciate that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a British/American difference here. The verb *provide* takes two objects, and they can go in either order. The second one usually takes a preposition, and the first one never does. The preposition depends on the order.

> Can you provide some good examples **for** me.
>   Can you provide me **with** some good examples.
>
> You should provide food **for** your dog before you go on vacation.
>   You should provide your dog **with** food before you go on vacation.

Americans do sometimes use two objects without prepositions if the "for" object is first and the "with" object second:

> You should provide your dog exercise on a regular basis.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_differences#Transitivity) says this is not allowed in British English.

Comment: Excellent research. Never trust them American dictionaries, even if they come from Oxford!

Answer (score 11):

Provide can be either transitive or intransitive.
All of your sentences above appear correct (as provide can take both a direct and an indirect object, and the "with" may be implied, as in your 2nd sentence).

> **1** [ trans. ] make available for use; supply : *these clubs provide a much appreciated service for this area.*
>   • ( provide someone with) equip or supply someone with (something useful or necessary) : *we were provided with a map of the area.*
>   • present or yield (something useful) : *neither will provide answers to these problems.*
>
> **2** [ intrans. ] ( provide for) make adequate preparation for (a possible event) : *new qualifications must provide for changes in technology.*
>   • supply sufficient money to ensure the maintenance of (someone) : *Emma was handsomely provided for in Frank's will.*
>   • (of a law) enable or allow (something to be done).
>
> **3** [with clause ] stipulate in a will or other legal document : *the order should be varied to provide that there would be no contact with the father.*
>
> **4** ( provide someone to) historical Christian Church appoint an incumbent to (a benefice).

source: NOAD

Comment: Do you real feel the second sentence sounds right: *Can you provide me some good examples?* — It somehow sounds a bit awkward. I'd say either "can you provide some good examples?" or "can you give me some good examples?".

Comment: @Cerberus I agree that it sounds a bit awkward and that *give* might be a better word choice, but I'm still pretty sure it is grammatically correct.

Comment: Fair enough. I think I'd rephrase it regardless.

Comment: @Cerberus: I just found a Wikipedia page that says "Can you provide me some good examples" is grammatical in American but not British English. I've posted another answer with this information.

Answer (score 5):

Other uses of *provide* could be:

> I told my girlfriend I could provide for her.
>   I can provide for you.
>   Can you provide an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding historical usage, it seems that “provide with” started to be used around 1750. A couple of Google ngram searches provided for the date it started being used. I was tipped off by the fact that, while King James’ Bible (1611) doesn't use it as a transitive verb, newer translations do.

Comment: "transitive" is the wrong word here, as Shakespeare's usage (which is the American usage the OP is asking about) was doubly transitive, and the current British usage is only singly transitive, but I think you're right: [Google Ngram.](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=provided+me+with+a%2Cprovided+me+a&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=10&share=)