# Preposition with verb "provide"

Tags: verbs, prepositions

It appears the transitive verb *provide* has (at least) two prepositions:

> provide (something) for (someone/something)
>
> provide (something) to (someone/something)

For example,

> The umbrellas provide shade for the guests.
>
> He provided drugs to the prisoners.

In both of these examples, one could have swapped *to* and *for*, although the sentences as written feel more natural.

Is there a good rule to use when deciding whether to use *to* or *for* with *provide*?

No doubt endless opining on this question is possible.  But I would very much prefer if someone could point me to some sort of authoritative source, e.g., OED, Cambridge ESL materials, Chicago Manual of Style.

Comment: Related: [Usage of the verb “provide”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18308/usage-of-the-verb-provide)

Comment: "if someone could point me to some sort of authoritative source" they would also likely vote to close your question as "general reference" :)

Comment: The point is I haven't found any good guidance yet in the OED or Chicago Style guide.  So if someone has insight, that would be great.  I am as contemptuous of questions that are easily answered by opening up a standard reference as anyone else.

Comment: There also exists "provide (someone/something) with (something)", which is closer in meaning to "provide (something) to (someone/something)" than to "provide (something) for (someone/something)".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you *provide for [someone/something in need]* without specifying exactly *what*, it means you make available to them whatever they need - often food (provisions/provender). You can also *provide for [some eventuality]* without specifying what, meaning you have plans/resources to deal with that eventuality should it come to pass. Both these usages have been around a long time, and always involve *for*, not *to*.

To *provide [something]* **to** *[someone]* is a [far more recent usage](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=provide%20it%20for,provide%20it%20to&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)...

[image]

Per @JeffSahol's answer, *provide X to Y* often implies that *Y* did actually receive *X*, whereas *provide X for Y* can be used even if *Y* doesn't avail himself of the *X* which is on offer. But often it's an idiomatic choice where people repeat the version they hear most. Other than that, the modern trend towards **to** clearly disambiguates from the first two usages given above.

Answer (score 13):

One shade of difference is the assumption that someone *providing x to* has actually delivered *x* to the person, not merely made sure that it was made available:

- If you provided umbrellas **for** your guests, that means that there is a supply of umbrellas available for their use.
- If you provided umbrellas **to** your guests, I would be more likely to assume they each have an umbrella in their hand.

Comment: +1 because you've identified the potential difference I missed! I've put that in my answer and credited you rather than delete mine, because I think the shift in prevalence is also important here.