# Our coach forbids (us) 'drinking'/'to drink'

Tags: grammar

In my grammar book "Grammatica Inglese Facile (Simple English Grammar)"  I read that the following sentences are both correct:

> - Our coach *forbids drinking*.
> - Our coach *forbids us to drink*.

But the book adds that the latter cannot rewritten in this way:

> - Our coach *forbids us drinking*.

However the book doesn't explain its last statement, thus I'm asking if someone can explain whether what the book states true is. If so, why?

Comment: Also note the first cannot be rewritten "our coach forbids *to drink*."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that the verb *forbid* is transitive but not doubly transitive. That is, it needs one object, but cannot take two objects. The object, however, can be either the thing forbidden or the person to which it is forbidden.

> I forbid it.
>   I forbid you.

(You can't just say "I forbid"; you need the "it" or "you", but either one works).

> Our coach forbids alcohol to the team.
>   Our coach forbids the team to drink alcohol.

I believe some dialects permit a doubly transitive *forbid*, but most dialects don't:

> *Our coach forbids the team alcohol.

Those people who do permit it would allow your last example.

This happens with other verbs as well, like *provide,* which is only doubly transitive in America—see [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18308/usage-of-the-verb-provide).

Comment: Can't I say: *I forbid!* as an order?

Comment: "Doubly transitive"? Like _elect_ or _choose_?

Comment: Doubly transitive, like "I gave you the tickets". You can have a direct object and an indirect object, both with no prepositions.

Comment: @Noah: You can't say "I forbid!"—that sounds like a non-native speaker to me. You have to say "I forbid it!" or "I forbid you!", which both work fine.

Comment: This answer assumes that *drinking* is being used as a noun in the "bad" example, and is accurate based on that premise.  But *drinking* here could also be a gerund; for example, if the sentence were "Our coach saw us drinking", *see* is not taking two objects. I think the last sentence possibly fails only on semantic grounds, and in the right context, doesn't even fail at all.  "Our couch doesn't forbid all drinking. Our coach forbids us drinking." I think this works.

Comment: Are you sure? The double-object form (that is, both direct and indirect objects, so fully transitive) seems perfectly standard to my (possibly jaded or antiquarian) ear. The OED has plenty of “double object” examples of *forbid*, such as from Dickens: “Will you forbid him the house where I know he's safe?” That said, the OED does go on to say that the specific form of *to forbid someone from doing something* is now **rare**, as in “He forbade both men and women from entering them.” That surprises me, as it seems completely current to me.

Comment: @tchrist: I'm not sure. [This Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=forbid+him+the%2Che+had+forbidden&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=5) seems to say that (1) the incidence of *forbid* is going down in general and (2) the double-object form is going down much faster.

Comment: @tchrist: looking at the recent instances of "forbid me the" in Google books, a lot of them are either reprints of older material or historical fiction, so I think the double-object construction is indeed archaic, although it may well still be used in some dialects.

Comment: "Our coach forbids the team to drink alcohol." is not grammatical in my dialect (RP English) "from drinking" would be what I would use. Speakers of other dialects seem to use infinitives more than participles, or maybe it is just non-native speakers (I don't know).

Answer (score 5):

"Forbids drinking" is OK because the gerund (V+ing) is the object of your verb.

When you want to mention both the person and the act, you can choose between:

1. forbid somebody to V
2. [forbid somebody from V+ing](http://blogs.newsobserver.com/grammar/word-advice-prepositions)

You can say "Our coach forbids drinking," and "Our coach forbids us from drinking."

Personally, I prefer to use "forbid to," though.

Comment: It's not just you, "forbid s.o. to" is [much more common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=forbids+me+to%2C+forbids+me+from&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) than "forbid s.o. from".

Comment: I think so too, Peter. But I didn't want to disregard the usage of  "forbid from," which has gained some degree of acceptance. Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes going with the less common could make you special, though:)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it could be said that *Our coach forbids the team alcohol* contains an implied *to*, making the team an indirect object; i.e. *Our coach forbids to the team alcohol*. (Admittedly *...alcohol to the team* sits better).

Similar to *Give it me!* = *Give it to me!*

Comment: However, grammar books normally state that the double-object construction is only possible when the direct object is either a noun or name, whereas it is to be avoided when it is a pronoun, in which case you are supposed to use the regular construction verb + direct object + indirect object.