# "provide" vs. "provide with"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, verbs, prepositions

I am wondering if the following sentence is correct:

> We add the information their study provides with to our article.

The context is: their study provides with some information. And we add the information to our article.

I want to keep the word "add", and someone told me that "provides with to" sounds wired...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Usage of the verb "provide"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18308/usage-of-the-verb-provide)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The verb *provide* has two different subcategorisation frames:

1. provide *something* [ **to** *somebody*]
2. provide *somebody* **with** *something*

In the first, the material provided is the object, in the second the recipient is the object.

Both are valid, and both are in common use. The difference between them is the *with* phrase, which must be there to get meaning 2: if there is only one (direct) object, then meaning 1 is the relevant one (the *to* phrase is optional).

The stranding you are doing can be grammatical, but because you are using *with*, it is grammatical only if the recipient is explicit as the direct object

> We add the information the study provides us with to our article.

(Thanks to Jonathan Spirit for the example)

If you are not expressing the recipient, you need to use pattern 1, which has no *with*:

> We add the information the study provides to our article.

Comment: In AmE, you can indeed say *"We add the information the study provides us to our article."* See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_American_and_British_English#Transitivity) and [this ELU.SE question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18308/usage-of-the-verb-provide).

Comment: That's true in BrE as well, and is an additional complication, but has no bearing on my point, which is that _if_ you use "with", _then_ you have to express the recipient (as direct object). The square brackets in my 1) were to convey that the recipient is optional in that form (of which your example is a regular transform which can generally be applied to bitransitive verbs, eg "Show it to me" = "Show me it".)

Comment: Can you provide me with a comprehensible example?

Comment: In the light of Peter's comment, and the many examples of  the ditransitive _3. provide somebody something (usually provide someone a way to..., eg_ << That may aid in students' development of critical thinking skills and provide them a way to communicate science in a language that is understood. >>...

Comment: {[Pedagogy in a New Tonality
edited by Peter Gouzouasis](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=y8ZFdSuYJicC&pg=PA230&lpg=PA230&dq=%22provide+them+a+way%22&source=bl&ots=V_HhH4s_TA&sig=TVHbJT7dC5rbUtcV4Qzo_1wJpm8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjev_PFxr7ZAhVRF8AKHQOgCPcQ6AEIMzAC#v=onepage&q=%22provide%20them%20a%20way%22&f=false)}), shouldn't the first section be revised?

Comment: Indeed, it would be simpler (and clearer) to say "We add the information _provided by_ the study to our article".

Answer (score 1):

With is a preposition. If we want to say, "provided with," we have to have something that the "with" modifies. We could revise this sentence to say,

> We add the information the study provides *us* with to our article.

In your original sentence, the prepositional phrase "with information" didn't modify any words. In this new sentence, "with information" modifies "us."

You could also use the second sentence, which is equally correct.

Comment: I agree with your conclusion, but not your explanation. Many prepositional phrases do not "modify" anything other than the whole circumstance expressed in the predicate (I would prefer to say that they express part of its meaning, rather than modify it). In your example _with information_ doesn't modify _us_ (in the way it would in _They saw us with the information_); rather, it specifies part of the activity of providing.