# "We provide you the ideal environment"

Tags: verbs, transitivity

I wonder if I can also write "We provide you the ideal environment" or only "we provide you with the ideal environment"

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137660/provide-vs-provide-with

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you want to say, "We provide you with the ideal environment." or "We provide the ideal environment for you." or just "We provide the ideal environment."

The sentence, "We provide you the ideal environment." reads awkwardly to a native English speaker in the U.S.

Comment: Yes, it looks like _provide_ is definitely a transitive predicate, and is working its way up to be bitransitive. With an indirect object, dative alternation doesn't work correctly in American English, but it's OK as long as the verb is considered to be _provide with_. Soon the _with_ in _provide with_ will become optional, like the _of_ in _because of_, because syntactic change.