# "Enter code you were provided with" - Is the "with" mandatory? Should it be omitted here?

Tags: word-choice, expressions

**EDIT: The main point of my question is about whether it's better to avoid ending a sentence with a preposition in this case.**

As text explaining to some software's user that they need to enter a code that was supplied to them, what would be the correct text? <sub>[I know the difference between `providing a car to someone` and `providing someone with a car`, **and I'm referring to the latter**. I'm asking if it's more correct to leave out the "with".]</sub>

1. Enter code you were provided
2. Enter code you were provided **with**

or maybe something else altogether?

(I didn't include a "the" after "Enter" because it seems like software text is usually succinct like that, but perhaps that should be added as well?)

**EDIT**

This is unrelated to ["provide" vs. "provide with"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/137660) . 
I know the difference between `providing a car to someone` and `providing someone with a car`, **and I'm referring to the latter**. My question is just whether it's better to leave out the "with" at the end of the sentence.

Comment: This is sort of problem the passive voice introduces. Both are okay, but I'd rather see *Enter the code we sent* or *Enter the code from our last email*.

Comment: @CloseVoters Why?

Comment: @YosefBaskin The problem with that is that this text is supposed to appear in an application without prior knowledge of how it will be used in the future. Though the code is most likely going to be sent by email, we don't know that for sure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["provide" vs. "provide with"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/137660/provide-vs-provide-with)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Not exactly. Since I know the difference between the two "provide"s, and am asking about the provide that _does_ go with the "with". My question is whether the "with" is required or if it's better to leave it out, especially because that means the sentence will end with a "with".

Comment: Colin Fine's answer shows the  two different subcategorisation frames:

provide something [ to somebody]
provide somebody with something //// So, a code was provided to you ... and you were provided with a code. The licensed variants of your sentence are correspondingly _Enter the code that was provided to you_ and _Enter the code that you were provided with._  //// 'Provide' hasn't yet made it into ditransitive territory *_provide somebody something._

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Just to make sure, `Enter the code that you were provided with.` is completely fine despite ending with "with"?

Comment: Definitely should be "*the* code".

Comment: Yes, totally grammatical. Look up 'ending sentences with a preposition' if you're a bit wary of doing so. But even better (and what most proficient Anglophones would expect: ie _idiomatic English_) is 'Enter the code provided.'

Comment: You could just go with "Code".

Answer (score 1):

You can provide something to someone.* And you can provide someone with something.† You can even provide someone something.‡

And you can do all that in the passive voice as well, as you have demonstrated with your examples.

First let's look at the possible active voice versions of your message:

> *We provided a code to you. Enter the code that we provided to you.*
>
> *We provided you with a code. Enter the code that we provided you with.*
>
> *We provided you a code. Enter the code that we provided you.*

Now let's make those passive:

> *A code was provided to you [by us]. Enter the code that was provided to you [by us].*
>
> *You were provided with a code [by us]. Enter the code that you were provided with [by us].*
>
> *You were provided a code [by us]. Enter the code that you were provided [by us].*

Finally let's shorten those back up:

> *Enter code provided.* (or *Enter provided code.*)
>
> *Enter code you were provided with.* (It's really completely legal to end a sentence with a preposition, but if you meet resistance . . .
>   *Enter the code with which you were provided.*)
>
> *Enter code you were provided.*

Take your pick. (I'd go with *Enter provided code.*)

> **provide,** *v.*
>
> * ‡ **6.** *transitive.* To supply (something) for use; to make
>   available; to yield, afford. Frequently with *for*, *to*, indicating
>   the beneficiary. Also occasionally with indirect object without *to*.
>
> <sub>1899  W. BESANT *Orange Girl* ii. xxvi. 431: The contractors..do
>   honestly provide the convicts the rations prescribed by the
>   Government.</sub>
>
> <sub>1942   LD. ALANBROOKE *Diary 26* May in *War Diaries* (2001) 260:
>   He is trying to stop deliveries of aircraft to us in order to provide
>   sufficient aircraft to USA pilots!</sub>
>
> † **10.** *transitive.* To supply (a person, animal, place, etc.) with
>   something. Frequently in *passive*.  **b.** With *with*.
>
> <sub>1913   C. GRAHAME-WHITE *Aviation 214*: The pilot and his
>   passenger are provided with a completely covered body, which they
>   enter through a small door.</sub>
>
> <sub>1990  S. FRASER in M. Kurc *That reminds Me* xi. 45: Since we
>   were all so famous, no one had provided us with namecards.</sub>
>
> <sub>Source: [Oxford English Dictionary](https://oed.com) (login
>   required)</sub>