# Provide vs. provide with

Tags: grammar

Could you please advise; which of the following is correct: 
1. Please ensure to provide Dan and me with your report by XX.
2. Please ensure to provide Dan and me your report by XX.

Many thanks

Comment: This is the sort of question where the asker should first consult a dictionary, and include the results in the post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Usage of the verb "provide"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18308/usage-of-the-verb-provide)

Comment: Since no one else seems inclined to give you a hint about what's wrong with **both** of the options you provide, let me point out that a native English speaker or writer would be very unlikely to use the wording "Please ensure to provide X"—where X is anything being provided to anyone. Instead, idiomatically, an English speaker would be far more likely to say "Please ensure that you provide X" or "Please be sure to provide X." The vast majority of English speakers simply don't use "ensure" with a following infinitive, as you use it in both of your options.

Answer (score 0):

It is OK to '*provide somebody with something*' or to '*provide something for/to somebody*'.

> Please be sure to provide Dan and me **with** your report by some date.
>
> Please be sure to provide your report **for/to** Dan and me by some date.

The version 'provide to' is less typical than 'provide for':

https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/everyday-grammar-prepositions-provide/2701412.html

Comment: And in American English (but not British English), you can *provide somebody something*. [See Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_grammatical_differences#Transitivity).